# Looking for 1940s marriage and divorce records from the Southwestern USA?

Tags: united-states, 20th-century, marriage-records, divorce-records

I'm looking for marriage and divorce records between Constance Marie Bonneville and Russell Almon Gilmore Lacey, my guess would around 1944 maybe in Arizona or California. Constance may have been married before Lacey to Wonderi. Constance had a son with the name Robert Lacey Wonderi, 29 Feb 1944. My guess is Wonderi took off and Constance married Lacey. I found a marriage between Bonneville and Wonderi in Yuma, Arizona no date, but no divorce.

Constance Marie Bonneville

- Birth: 29 March 1925, Biddeford, York, Maine, United States
- Death: 25 January 1998, Lake Isabella, Kern, California, United States

Russell Almon Gilmore Lacey

- Birth: 14 December 1914, Globe, Gila, Arizona, United States
- Death: 10 July 1982, Guymon, Texas, Oklahoma, United States

They had a daughter born in 1948 in California.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to G&FH.SE!  Could you add a brief note about where you've searched already and what records you have in hand?  There are some tips in the [help] such as [How do I ask a good question?](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Iv searched ca and az

Comment: I have the birth and death of robert. The marriage and when looked back it also said divorce of Bonneville and Wonder. I just can't find marriage and divorce records between Constance Marie Bonneville and Russell Almon Gilmore Lacey. They got married before robert Wonder was born and after they had a child together a daughter born in 1948 in California. Tone Lynn Lacey. I'm pulling my hair out!

Comment: I understand you've searched for records for CA and AZ and the other things you've mentioned in your comments and question, but what I don't know is *how* and *where* you searched for them.  If you don't tell us, it's difficult for people to suggest other options.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to the question, but as a starting point, I suggest you obtain the birth and death certificate for the son Robert born in 1942.

In the [California Birth Index entry](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:VGFP-92B) on FamilySearch, Robert's birth is indexed as:

> Name: **Robert Lee Wandrei**
>   Event Type: Birth
>   Event Date: 27 Aug 1942
>   Event Place: Los Angeles, California, United States
>   Gender: Male
>   Mother's Name: Bomeville

His entry in the [California Death Index](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:VG5J-1D4):

> Name: **Robert Lacey Wonderi**
>   Event Type: Death
>   Event Date: 29 Feb 1944
>   Event Place: Los Angeles, California, United States
>   Birth Date: 27 Aug 1942
>   Birthplace: California
>   Gender: Male
>   Father's Name: Wonderi
>   Mother's Name: Bonneville

California certificates can be obtained from the [California DPH](http://www.cdph.ca.gov/certlic/birthdeathmar/Pages/default.aspx) or county offices.

These certificates should provide his parent's names, which may help identify his mother's first marriage and possible divorce. Keep in mind that they may not have actually married so there may be no marriage and divorce record to find.

Comment: Minor quibble: even though the birthdates match and the mother's maiden name is close, these two records might belong to two different people.

Comment: @JanMurphy Possible but extremely unlikely. Genealogy is a game of probabilities and uncertainties. Also see http://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GRid=167209732